# Image upload in PHP error - type required

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying for days to upload an image through PHP and OAuth2 to App.net.
Below is the PHP I'm using - it results in this error:

> "error_message":"Bad Request: 'type': Required."

```
<?php
function sendPost()
{
$postData = array(
     'type' => 'com.example.upload',
);
$ch = curl_init('https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/files');
$headers = array('Authorization: Bearer '.'0123456789',
                  'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"; filename="http://www.example.com/pics/test.jpg";type=image/jpeg',
          'Content-Type: image/jpeg',
                 );
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
}       

sendPost();
?>
```

This is their cURL example from the [API documentation](http://developers.app.net/docs/resources/file/):

```
curl -k -H 'Authorization: BEARER ...' https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/files -X POST -F 'type=com.example.test' -F "content=@filename.png;type=image/png" -F "derived_key1=@derived_file1.png;type=image/png" -F "derived_key2=@derived_file2.png;type=image/png;filename=overridden.png"
```

What type is required and what do I need to change to make it work?

Any feedback is really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do these following changes

```
$headers = array(
     'Authorization: Bearer '.'0123456789'
);

$postData = array('type' => 'com.example.upload', 'content' => '@/roor/test.png');
```

Also use this as you are using https

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);
```

Comment: Just tried it and got a new error: "failed creating formpost data". What could be the problem?

Comment: Use local file instead of http url image.

Comment: Sorry, can you please show me an example? Currently it looks like this: `$postData = array('type' => 'com.example.upload', 'content' => "@/pics/test.jpg");`

Comment: Your code is correct. Does this image `/pics/test.jpg` exist on that location?

Comment: Yes it exists on that location. The PHP file is in `example.com/oauth/` and the image is in `example.com/oauth/pics/test.jpg` What could cause the error?

Comment: Just found this from the documentation: `To create a complete file object, send a POST with an HTTP header of Content-Type: multipart/form-data. Our API expects one part of the request body to contain a Content-Disposition header with a value for filename and name="content". The data from this part will be used as the file’s content.`  Do I need to add something from that to the script or is it automatically included? Thanks for your help.

Comment: This content type header adds automatically when you do upload using @ sign. I have updated the post. Please revise it again.